# jQuery Mobile: Refresh input widget value in Webkit Browsers

Tags: refresh, jquery-mobile

I'm building a web-app using jQuery Mobile.  I'm trying to use javascript to set the value of an input widget in a function bound to the "pageshow" event.  It works in Firefox but fails in Webkit browsers (Safare, Mobile Safari, Chrome...).

The following is defined as part of the $(document).ready() function:

```
$('#decimal').live('pageshow', function(event, ui){
  $('#dLat').val(gps.latitude)
  $('#dLong').val(gps.longitude);
  gps.altitude = null;
});
```

The html for the JQM "page" is:

```
<div data-role="page"  id="decimal" data-theme="c" > 
  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Decimal Entry</h1>  
  </div> 
  <div data-role="controlgroup"  class="dInput">
    <label for="dLat">Lat: </label>
    <input type="number" class="dInput" name="dLat" id="dLat" value=""><br>
    <label for="dLong">Lon: </label>
    <input type="number" class="dInput" name="dLong" id="dLong" value=""><br>
  </div>
  <a href="#manual" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="btnDecimalSubmit"> Done </a>
</div>
```

Do Webkit browsers require an additional refresh of some sort?  If so, how do I do that for <input...> elements?

The submit pseudo-button also fails to close the dialog, but only on Webkit browsers.

Comment: try pagebeforeshow instead of pageshow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code by laying it out in a stand-alone page as follows (with jQM alpha), and this works in WebKit. I appreciate that this isn't running as a dialog, but I'm not aware of any differences in WebKit due to this.

I suspect part of the issue may be that you have the `pageshow` stuff wrapped in `$(document).ready` -- you don't need to do that. Here's how the Javascript section in my test page looks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#decimal').live('pageshow', function(event, ui){
     $('#dLat').val(55.5603);
     $('#dLong').val(56.1356);
  });
</script>
```

(I removed the `gps` variable and set hard-coded values because obviously I don't have that piece of the code).

Comment: Poole I'm puzzled.   The pageshow stuff was wrapped in $(document).ready, but taking it out didn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this!   I built a small test case using static data at [link](http://netfools.com/test23/) and it seems to work fine.

The big (messy) version that uses geolocation [link](http://netfools.com/position) fails.   

I'm baffled as to how to go about debugging this.  I added a console.log statement to the pageshow function and looks like it never gets triggered in Chrome.

I'll report whatever I ultimately find back here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In researching the problem I see pundits writing introductions to jQuery Mobile that contain phrases like "Every page must fit the jQuery Mobile standard."  ...but they never seem to provide a link to that "standard".   Clearly they're correct.  I made some changes to the page and it now works (plus or minus some formatting problems).  But I'm at a loss to tell which change fixed the problem!   jQuery Mobile is clearly well ahead of the jQuery Mobile docs.

Comment: @RAMilewski Glad it's sorted! FWIW, if page events aren't tied to the specific page id being manipulated, and the code being called isn't referenced on the physical html file wherein the page code lies, things go awry. It's weird I grant you that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I ran into this problem before. Try using the mobileinit event instead of the document ready event.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
$("#somePage").live( 'pageshow', function( event ) {
    Do some stuff here
```

That fixed a similar problem for me I hope it helps.